# asp.net Textbox Textmode Number, allow numbers only

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would just like to know if there is a way in ASP.NET to allow only numbers in textboxes with `textmode="number"`

when I use this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="Number" ID="TextBoxDuration" Width="250"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="TextBoxDuration" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Dieses Feld darf nicht leer sein" /><br />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxDuration" validationexpression="((\d+)((\.\d{1})?))$" ErrorMessage="Nur Zahlen" />
```

users can still input the char `e` and `+, -`

I don't like to use normal Textbox with the same `Regularexpressionvalidator` (which actually would work)

example:

[image]

Comment: The characters e, E, +, and - are valid characters for numbers. E and e denote scientific notation and + and - denote positive and negative numbers respectively. You may be able to use a masked edit control (third party) to further limit the characters that can be input.

Comment: thx, but `expressionvalidator` and `texmode="number"` wont work together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery like this

```
Number : <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" />&nbsp;<span id="errmsg"></span>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //called when key is pressed in textbox
            $("#quantity").keypress(function (e) {
                //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
                if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                    //display error message
                    $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use regular expression validator as

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1" runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="Only Numbers allowed"
    ValidationExpression="\d+">

</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Also you can use the below regular expression to make the text-field as 12 digit number to be added.(madatory)

```
^[0-9]{12}$
```

Also you can make the field as between 10 and 12 digits (mandatory) as below

```
^[0-9]{10-12}$
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use RegularExpressionValidator for this. below is the sample code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Only Numbers allowed" ValidationExpression="\d+"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

above TextBox only allowed integer to be entered because in RegularExpressionValidator has field called ValidationExpression, which validate the TextBox. However, you can modify as per your requirement.

You can see more example in MVC and Jquery [here](http://www.mitracircle.com/post/1/allow-only-integers-in-a-textbox).

Answer (score 2):

you can make a Javascript function into your Textbox.

Try `<asp:TextBox ID="txtNumero" Text="" onkeydown="return jsDecimals(event);" Width="75px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`

Then

```
function jsDecimals(e) {

    var evt = (e) ? e : window.event;
    var key = (evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode : evt.which;
    if (key != null) {
        key = parseInt(key, 10);
        if ((key < 48 || key > 57) && (key < 96 || key > 105)) {
            //Here is where respond with 0 o 1.
            if (!jsIsUserFriendlyChar(key, "Decimals")) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (evt.shiftKey) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

REGEX

```
^[0-9]*$


<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbAccount"
    ErrorMessage="Please Enter Only Numbers" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^\d+$">        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

IF YOU DON'T WANT USER TO TYPE OTHER CHARACTER ON KEY EVENT THEN

```
$('#TEXTBOXID').keypress(function (e) {
    var a = [];
    var k = e.which;

    for (i = 48; i < 58; i++)
    a.push(i);

    // allow a max of 1 decimal point to be entered

    if (!(a.indexOf(k) >= 0)) e.preventDefault();


});
```

Comment: The `RegularExpressionValidator` dont work seems like i really have to use JQuery thx

Comment: Yes..Regular expression only work after you change the focus.you can use key event to prevent user from entering non numeric characters using jquery..

Answer (score 1):

you can use filter textbox extender.
it will allows only number.
there is no negative numbers or e,+,- keys

```
<asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="TextBox1_FilteredTextBoxExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtDay"  FilterType="Numbers"> </asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use asp.net field validate like this

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control"  ID="txtNumero"  />
                                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
                                                    ID="txtNumero"
                                                    ControlToValidate="EmailTextBox"
                                                    Text="(Invalid number)"
                                                    ForeColor="Red"
                                                    ValidationExpression="^\d+$"
                                                    runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding Type="number" will work.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQty"  type="number" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Adding `type="number"` is virtually the same. This won't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the code-behind, just set

```
this.TextBoxDuration.Attributes["type"] = "number";
```