# Limit Input Type in a Textbox

Tags: asp.net

I'm new to all this and trying to only allow numeric values to be entered into an existing `TextBox` in `ASP.Net`. I've got the code for this, but can't figure out where to put it in. If I do it like the below, it creates an additional box in the textbox (that works). How can I apply this limitation to the current textbox?

```
<asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtS2" runat="server" Width="95%" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="WerklikChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    <input type="text" onkeypress="filterDigits(event)"/>
</asp:TableCell>
```

Update:

I ended up using the below, which is not really what I wanted as it still only checks the field once I leave the field. I'll look into blocking the entry of letters completely at a later stage and post the answer here.

```
<asp:CompareValidator
ID="ProgrammaticID"
ControlToValidate="txtS2KoringA"
Type="Double"
Operator="DataTypeCheck"
ErrorMessage="Error Message"
Text=" Net nommers word toegelaat in die 'Werklik' velde"
ForeColor="Red"
BackColor="White"
SetFocusOnError="false"
Display="Dynamic"
runat="server"> 
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net Textbox Textmode Number, allow numbers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880654/asp-net-textbox-textmode-number-allow-numbers-only) or [How to allow only integers in a textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732455/how-to-allow-only-integers-in-a-textbox)

Comment: Thanks Siva, however, the other question only checks the input when moving out of the cell and then clears it. I want it to ignore the input if the user tries to input a letter, just like the "input" section in my original post does. I just want it to apply that constraint to the current textbox and not create it's own.

Comment: Any client side functionality extension you need, try the jQuery/Javascript based solution but make sure you validate input on server side as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net Textbox Textmode Number, allow numbers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880654/asp-net-textbox-textmode-number-allow-numbers-only)